# added new user no shell/ tab completing

Tags: 12.04, users

I added a new ubuntu user with this command

```
 useradd -d /home/newname -m newname
```

It seems no tab completing  feature and only $ as prompt, When I logged in as root I see root@server$ as prompt.

Something is missing for my new user?

THanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sounds like your user was added with the sh shell instead of bash
try the following.

su to your new user and type `chsh` type `/bin/bash` and press enter
now try reloging and see if it works

Comment: by default `useradd` reads a file `/etc/default/useradd` which by default has this set `SHELL=/bin/sh`. `adduser` on the other hand config defaults to bash `DSHELL=/bin/bash`

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem and I managed to correct it with `useradd` itself. Indeed, you can set the initial shell for the user while creating the user, with `-s` option:

```
useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/newname -m newname
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats odd. All this should be in your .bashrc and bash profiles I believe. *That* should have been populated by /etc/skel. All this leads me to think there's a deeper issue with your install.

Answer (score 0):

Executing with `sudo` privilege worked

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash user_name_here
```