# Create the home directory while creating a user

Tags: adduser

I have added user using the `adduser` command, but a directory with is new user name is not created in `/home`, and I'm also not able to run any command with this user. After logging from this user it's only showing($) on the screen using a cli

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Find and open **Users and Groups**. Delete that user, and create a new one

There is more on using it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups).

[image: Users and Groups]

---

For command line, these should work:

```
useradd -m USERNAME
```

You have to use `-m`, otherwise no home directory will be created. If you want to specify the path of the home directory, use `-d` and specify the path:

```
useradd -m -d /PATH/TO/FOLDER USERNAME
```

You can then set the password with:

```
passwd USERNAME
```

All of the above need to be run as root, or with the `sudo` command beforehand. For more info, run `man adduser`.

Hope this helps [image: smiley]

Comment: be careful, using the command line option (useradd) apparently doesn't default the shell to bash [!] http://askubuntu.com/questions/281217/added-new-user-no-shell-tab-completing possibly suggest using `adduser` instead

Comment: There's the `-s` option to set their login shell with `useradd`, in case you're not able to use `adduser` for some reason. `sudo useradd -m -s $(which bash) -G sudo <USERNAME>` will create a new user with a home dir, bash login shell and the ability to `sudo`.

Comment: `useradd` is a low level utility, [I would use `adduser myuser` instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/374878/349837), and `adduser myuser sudo` to for eg, to add `myuser` to `sudo` group